Mapbox Kotlin error conflict libc++_shared.so
I have a problem with Mapbox implementation for my Kotlin application
I followed the documentation: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/#add-the-dependency
Well almost, for step 2 is in my build.gradle (project) like this:
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            gradlePluginPortal()
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
                url = uri("https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven")
                // Do not change the username below. It should always be "mapbox" (not your username).
                credentials.username = "mapbox"
                // Use the secret token stored in gradle.properties as the password
                credentials.password = providers.gradleProperty("MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN").get()
                authentication { basic(BasicAuthentication) }
            }
        }
    }

Unfortunately during the build I have a conflict problem:
2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so' from inputs:

C:\Users\johanke.gradle\caches\transforms-3\b8c059599cd20d9173eec748d219fd64\transformed\jetified-pdfium-android-1.9.0\jni\arm64-v8a\libc++_shared.so
C:\Users\johanke.gradle\caches\transforms-3\1d2cd570d97102124d90dc5c2939e546\transformed\jetified-common-24.3.1\jni\arm64-v8a\libc++_shared.so
If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see
https://developer.android.com/r/tools/jniLibs-vs-imported-targets

There appear to be two versions of the libc++_shared.so file.
To try to correct the problem I did this
Gemini advise me this
    android {
        packagingOptions {
            // Exclude the unnecessary library's architecture (e.g., arm64-v8a)
            exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
        }
    }

Without success, I also tried this with the help of ChatGPT
    android {
        ...
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
            exclude 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
            exclude 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
            exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        }
        ...
    }

So yes it builds well but the application crashes.
This is probably a conflict problem with another implementation but I don't know how to resolve the problem while keeping the dependencies, could someone help me with this.
Here is the list of dependencies:
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.9.10"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"

    // Compose
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:1.5.4"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.5.4"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2:1.5.4"

    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'

    //Lifecycle
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.2"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.2"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.6.2"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'

    //Kotlin Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.1"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.1"

    //Hilt
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48.1'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.48.1'

    //Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.0"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.0"

    //Navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.4"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.4"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0'

    //Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.15.1'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.15.1'

    //Timber
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:5.0.1'

    // okHttp3 pour télécharger des documents
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0")
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.1'

    // Google play service pour coords
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'

    // JWT
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.5'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.5'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.11.5'

    // PDF
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.13.2'
    implementation ('com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1')

    // Dépendances Firebase
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.3')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx' // Crashlytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx' // Remote config
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx' // Analytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf-ktx' // Performance

    // Worker pour les notifications push
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.1"

    // Picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    // Carousel
    implementation 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.4'

    // Skeleton loader
    implementation "com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0"

    // EncryptedSharedPreference
    implementation "androidx.security:security-crypto:1.1.0-alpha06"

    // Mapbox
    implementation 'com.mapbox.maps:android:11.3.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

For more informations :
Version Kotlin: 1.9.10
Gradle JDK: JetBrains Runtime Version 17.0.10

TLDR: You should use pickFirst instead of exclude.
Reason
There is 2 libraries, which try to include libc++_shared.so. And it leads to conflict.
Solution
Ask Gradle to pick any one of libc++_shared.so:
// build.gradle.kts
android {
    packaging {
        jniLibs.pickFirsts.add("**/libc++_shared.so")
    }
}

